# Using file functions to reverse the characters in the file

Tags: c, loops, pointers, fseek, ftell

So, using fseek and ftell function I am trying to print the characters one at a time by first pointing to the end of the file using fseek and then decrementing the value of ftell to print the last character and then print the previous ones.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp=NULL;
    char i=0,count=0;

    fp= fopen("note.txt","r");
    if(fp==NULL){   printf("File error");
            return -1;}

    fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
    count=ftell(fp);

    while(count){

        count--;
       fseek(fp,count,SEEK_END);
        i=fgetc(fp);
        printf("%c",i);


    }
    fclose(fp);
    fp=NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

My code is printing some strange characters so it isn't working, any suggestion on where I am going wrong in the while loop?

Comment: Here: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fseek.3.html Check what `fseek(fp,count,SEEK_END);` is doing. It's **not** doing what you seem to think.

Comment: Don't you want `SEEK_SET` inside the loop? With `SEEK_END` it appears you're trying to seek past the end of the file.

Comment: You're reading from the end of the file (actually even past the end of the file) over and over again. You need to read the last character, then the second to the last charcacter and so on until you're at the beginning of the file.